# limit selection of a row only to checkbox not with entire row in angular 6 mat-table

Tags: angular, angular6, mat-table

I need to restrict the table rows from being selected only by clicking on corresponding check boxes not with clicking anywhere on the row.While any of the row is selected, action bar is showed.

The issue here i'm facing is when i clicks on the row, checkbox is selected and also the action bar is showed up. I need to show action bar only when selection made through checkbox.

Here is the demo link : https://angular-kmeypw.stackblitz.io

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer.

Remove (click)="selection.toggle(row)" from the last tr it should be

```
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
  </tr>
```